# Access a float in a class, in a namespace

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I'm trying to change the value of 'XSensitivity' in the script below from another script.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
[Serializable]
public class HeadLook
{
    public float XSensitivity = 8f;
    public float YSensitivity = 8f;
    public float MinimumX = -60F;
    public float MaximumX = 60F;

    public float xRotRaw;
    public float yRotRaw;

    public HeadLook (float rotX, float rotY)
    {
        rotX = XSensitivity;
        rotY = YSensitivity;
    }
    // create an instance (an Object) of the HeadLook class
    public HeadLook MyHeadLook = new HeadLook(8,8);

    private float xRot;
    private float yRot;

    private float xRotation;
    private float yRotation;

    //          ----------------------------
    public void LookRotation(Transform character, Transform head)
    {
        yRotRaw = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("HorizontalLook");
        xRotRaw = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("VerticalLook");

        yRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("HorizontalLook") * XSensitivity;
        xRot = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("VerticalLook") * YSensitivity;

        yRotation -= yRot * 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        yRotation = yRotation % 360;
        xRotation += xRot * 10 * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, MinimumX, MaximumX);
        head.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-xRotation, -0, 0);
        character.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -yRotation, 0);
    }
    //          ----------------------------
}
}
```

I thought this might work but I get an error.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

private HeadLook m_HeadLook;

void Awake ()
{
    m_HeadLook = GetComponent< HeadLook >();
    sensitivitySlider.value =  m_HeadLook.MyHeadLook.XSensitivity;
}
```

The error I get is ..
ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'HeadLook' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

Thanks.

Comment: The class does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`, therefore you cannot get the component of it, since it is not a component. Try finding the script that contains an instance of `HeadLook`.

Comment: The line the error is on is. m_HeadLook = GetComponent< HeadLook >();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private HeadLook m_HeadLook;

```
void Awake ()
{
    m_HeadLook = new HeadLook(8f,8f);
    sensitivitySlider.value =  m_HeadLook.MyHeadLook.XSensitivity;
}
```

You can't use GetComponent on it since it is not a MonoBehaviour.

Also, your HeadLook seems to be creating a HeadLook object that is not really necessary. You seem to try to do a Singleton and that would be more like:

```
public static HeadLook MyHeadLook = null;

public HeadLook (float rotX, float rotY)
{
    if(MyHeadLook != null) {return;}
    MyHeadLook = this;
    rotX = XSensitivity;
    rotY = YSensitivity;
}
```

This is really simplified but it will be a start for singleton.

EDIT: Someone in the comment section makes it a mission to make sure you use singleton properly. My answer was just a quick hint at the fact you were doing wrong and I was providing something simple to get you going.
So here is a link to a page that explains it fully.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

Answer (score 1):

You only need to derive your class from monobehaviour:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
[Serializable]
public class HeadLook : MonoBehaviour
{
...
```

Comment: you should derive from MB when needed. Maybe it is in this case but usually, if there is no need for inspector assignment or any callback from engine (Update, UI event,...) it is better to avoid the MB as it adds memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Error says it: "**GetComponent requires that the requested component 'HeadLook' derives from MonoBehaviour**"

Potential fixes:

1. Derive HeadLook from MonoBehavior and don't define constructor for HeadLook (you should set rotX and rotY by some other means)
2. Set HeadLook as a member of your calling script, in which case you won't use GetComponent (i.e. m_HeadLook = new HeadLook(1f,2f))